# how to find the coordinates of the point based on distance?

Tags: math

I have 2 points and both are 3d points i.e A(x,y,z) and B(x,y,z).
   I know the coordinates of point a and the distance between them. 
   How to find the coordinates of point B?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only know the absolute distance between the two points, you cannot find the coordinates of point B.  If you think about it, knowing one point and a distance defines a sphere.

However, if you know the difference between the coordinates in the x, y, and z axes, its as simple as adding the difference to point A to obtain point B.

Comment: if I know the y of the second point and z is the function of x then would it be possible?

Comment: No, it's not, knowing one coordinate only defines a plane

Comment: No problem.  Glad we could help.